# Сортировка в разделах laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как в laravel организовать сортировку по *id* (`DESC`, `ASC`) в категории? Если пагинация формирует линки вида `site.ru/cat/1?page=2`, 
как передать в `url` значение `orderBy`?

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере:

```
$cat = Cat::orderBy('column', $request->get('order'))->paginate(15);
```

Во вью:

```
$cat->appends(['order' => 'ASC/DESC'])->links();
```

[Ссылка на оф. документацию (раздел Appending To Pagination Links)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination)

Если нужно больше параметров в пагинацию передавать, то проще вот так:

```
{!! $cat->appends(Request::query())->render() !!}
```